# Is the use of a female noun suffix dependent on the usage of the indefinite article?

Tags: noun, gender, article

Would it be more normal, as a woman, to say 'Ich bin Europäer', rather than 'Ich bin Europäerin'?

Is it that 'Ich bin Europäer' is correct, and if one wished to use 'Europäerin' one would rather use the indefinite article and say 'Ich bin eine Europäerin'?

Comment: So normal wie "Ich bin ein Mitglied der Partei" (das Mitglied, auch für Frauen und Männer) oder "Ich bin eine Karteileiche" (die Leiche, auch für Männer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *-in* suffix for marking a female profession or association to a kind or group of females is a bit tricky to use. The indefinite article isn't involved in this, though.

> Ich bin Europäer.
>
> Ich bin Europäerin.

As a woman you can use both of these and you are correct. By using the *-in* suffix you only add the information telling everyone you are a woman is very important to you – people will draw their conclusions.

> Sie ist Europäer.
>
> Sie ist Europäerin.

Both are as valid, though the latter is more common.

> Das sind Europäer.
>
> Das sind Europäerinnen und Europäer.

Both are valid, but only people with a stick up their … spine use the latter one. It's just too inconvenient.

---

About the use of the indefinite article:

> Ich bin ein Europäer.
>
> Ich bin eine Europäerin.

Again, both are as valid. The difference to the example without the indefinite article is subtle, as the use of no/indefinite/definite articles tells apart **kinds** from **identical items out of a group** from **certain items**, and in this example, kind and group *Europäer* are identical on a semantic level. This is often the case.

You have to make up more specific examples to see the difference:

> Sie ist Lehrerin von Beruf.
>
> Sie ist eine Lehrerin unter vielen.
>
> Sie ist die Lehrerin meiner Deutschklasse.
>
> Sie ist die Lehrerin, nicht eine der Schülerinnen.

German doesn't make a difference between the indefinite article *ein* ("a") and the counter *ein* ("one"). This sometimes confuses learners. Take *ein* as a matter of last resort, when you don't have multiple items to select from a group, and you don't want to select a **specific** item either. You use "one" then – *ein*.

Comment: "By using the -in suffix you only add the information telling ever[y]one you are a woman is very important to you" This is not at all how I would perceive this.

Comment: So drawing conclusions just starts one step earlier for you.

Comment: –1 for the stick up their spine. While it is true that using *Europäerinnen und Europäer* in the example is not most people’s first choice, I find your word choice rather derogative.

Comment: That English expression means *someone who is particularistic, ridged, and not flexible. Not fun, cannot see humor, and overall, unpleasant.* Point proven.

Answer (score 0):

Ich bin Europäer is generic masculine as used to abbreviate legal expression in equal standing.
Ich bin Europäerin is used to express both continental and sexual identity and also a need for female visibility.  Ein:e just shrinks me to one of millions.

Comment: Kannst Du das mit der Visibility erklären?

Comment: English is centuries ahead in this.  It is proven that masculine wording makes listeners/readers fantasize males and to forget about females.  Females feel discouraged to apply as Direktorin when a Direktor is wanted.  I could for instance say Ich bin Europäerin or In mir steckt eine Afrikanerin to enhance female visibility by switching to the generic feminine.

Comment: Uiuiui! Sind Sprachen in einem Wettrennen in die gleiche Richtung, oder wie kann Englisch voraus sein? Dass das generische Mask. Frauen vergessen lässt ist durch die Geschichte d. dt. Sprache vielfach widerlegt. Stellenanzeigen sind qua Rechtsprechung inzw. ein eigenes Feld. "Ich bin Europäerin" ist gerade nicht generisch, sondern spezifisch. "Die Katze, die Maus" sind gen. Fem., "die Afrikanerin" nicht und in mir stecken wahrscheinlich ähnliche viele Afrikanerinnerinnen, wie Afrikaner oder in Dir. Es rückt die Frauen ins Bewusstsein weil es eben nicht generisch ist; es grenzt die Männer aus.

Comment: Norwegisch ist dem Deutschen darin voraus, dass es nicht mehr einundzwanzig dreht, Polnisch und Italienisch darin, dass man die Aussprache und Betonung vom Blatt ablesen kann, Chinesisch dadurch, dass die Schriftzeichen auch in Japan, Korea und Vietnam bekannt sind, Englisch durch das Weglassen von Höflichkeitsschwurbelei und Genderformen.  Gegen die Ausgrenzung von Männern steht es uns frei, bewusst mit dem Maskulinum zu provozieren, wie es uns freisteht, uns durch mehr Feminina nicht provozieren zu lassen.  In jedem Menschen steckt eine Afrikanerin, nämlich die erste.

Comment: Was heißt "nicht mehr 21 dreht"? Das mit der Aussprache hängt doch davon ab, von welcher Aussprache ich ausgehe. Ein Franzose oder Engländer kommt doch, wenn er italienische Wörter liest, zu einer anderen Aussprache als ein Deutscher - oder nicht? Und die dt. Schriftzeichen sind - größtenteils - auch in Österreich, der Türkei, den USA, dem Kongo und in Australien bekannt. Höflichkeitsschwurbelei lässt auch der Berliner gerne weg. ...

Comment: Früher sagten die Norweger übersetzt auf einundzwanzig, jetzt sagen sie zwanzigundeins.  Polnisch und Italienisch vom Blatt lesen zu können, setzt Kenntnis eines kurzen Buchkapitels von Ausspracheregeln voraus.  Im Englischen, Russischen, Französischen, Deutschen musst Du das ganze Wörterbuch an Betonungen auswendig kennen.